# How to put url(image) inside -ms-linear-gradient

Tags: css

I was trying to put a background image on my website, and then put a gradient on it, it works well in chrome but not in IE11.
i use this style for chrome :

```
background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(26 179 148 / .9), #3f9480),url(../img/pattern.jpg);
```

[it should be look like this(chrome)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWDZb.jpg)
and this for IE11 :

```
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #1ab394 0%, #3f9480 100% ),url(../img/pattern.jpg);
```

[it looks like this in IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS43w.jpg)
but it only shows the gradient, how do I put the URL(img)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same CSS setting for both Chrome and IE11 but need to change the definition of the color that has the transparency.

Use:

```
background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(26,179,148, .9), #3f9480),url(gear.jpg);
```

You don't need the -ms- prefix for IE11 as it deals with linear-gradient now. It just ignored the original transparency setting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out in a new HTML file not directly in your project

Html:

```
    <div class="tab">
       <div class="gradient"><!--
         Your input fields go here
         -->
       </div>
       <div class="container"></div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
        .gradient {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100px;
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #1ab394 0%, #3f9480 100%);
        opacity: 0.9;
    }

    .container {
        background-image: url('pattern.jpg');
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
    }
```

This is what it looks like in my IE11
[image]

This is the best I can do I hope you like it

Comment: Hi, I think there's a typo in your answer  - 'absolutes'.

Comment: It's work! Thanks for your answer, I try it in a new HTML, I'll modify it to my project.

Comment: No Problem I am glad to help :)